# Install CocoaPods error

Tags: terminal, cocoapods

When I write pod install in terminal I have:
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] The `master` repo is not a git repo.
What does mean? How to repair?

Comment: There was a git bug which crashed their repo you need to clone it fresh again as far I remember

Comment: Thank you! it helped here:"sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos" and "pod setup"